# Radius of convergence of a series with bounded coefficient sequence having no limit points inside unit disc

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $a_{0}, a_{1}, \ldots$ be a sequence of complex numbers
with $\left|a_{n}\right|<1$ such that the sequence $\left\{a_{n}\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ has no
limit point inside the unit disc $B(0,1)$. Prove that
the radius of convergence of the power series
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} z^{n}
$$ is 1.

How can we prove by using the limit supremum formula (Cauchy -Hadamard) here? Since it is a decreasing (by modulus) subsequence.

Comment: If $(a_n)$ has no limit point in the open unit disk then  $|a_n| \to 1$ and $|a_n|^{1/n} \to 1$.

Comment: Sir, How to jusify that $|a_n|$ converges to 1 ?

Comment: It doesn't (that is, it doesn't have to). It's the sequence $\left(|a_n|^{1/n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ that converges to $1$.

Comment: Can we prove this using $e^{(\ln |a_n|)/n}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use the Cauchy hadamard formula. To prove that the radius of convergence is $1$, it suffices to prove that for every $z:|z|<1$, the sum converges, and that for $|z|>1$ the sum diverges

- $|z|<1\rightarrow \sum |a_n||z^n|\le \sum |z|^n=\frac{1}{1-z}<+\infty$
- $|z|\ge 1\rightarrow \liminf_{n\to \infty}|a_nz^n|\ge \liminf |a_n|>0 $ (since otherwise $\{a_n\}$ would have an accumulation point in $0$), and thus the series cannot converge.